# Default Style of subcontrols in a custom DataGrid control

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I am developing a custom `DataGrid` control that derives from the standard WPF `DataGrid` to extend it with some client-specific needs.

Snippet of my `.cs` file:

```
public class DataGrid : System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid
{
    #region Constructor
    static DataGrid()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DataGrid)));
    }
}
```

Snippet of my `.xaml` file:

```
<Style TargetType="local:DataGrid"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type DataGrid}}">
```

By not using the `x:Key` on the `Style` tag, I declare this Style as default one for the control. This works as I expect it.

What I do not get is how I correctly declare Default Styles for subcontrols which are used by the `DataGrid`, like `DataGridRow`, `DataGridColumn` or `DataGridColumnHeader`.

---

One way is to declare it like this...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
```

... and set the `CellStyle` of my `local:DataGrid` explicitly (otherwise it still uses the standard WPF style for some reason(?))

```
<Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}"/>
```

When clients use this custom `DataGrid` locally, they can modify the Style by simply referring to `{x:Type DataGridCell}`, which I find pretty elegant:

```
<local:DataGrid>
    <lolcal:DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
```

The disadvantage of declaring it as Default Style is that when clients are using the standard WPF `DataGrid`, the Default Styles are overriden by my custom `DataGrid`.

---

The alternative way is to use the `x:Key` attribute when specifying my `DataGridCell` Style...

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyleKey" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
```

... and set the `CellStyle` of my `local:DataGrid` to this Key

```
<Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}" />
```

This way I don't override a Default Style, but when my clients want to locally modify the CellStyle, they need to reference the `x:Key` explicitely:

```
<local:DataGrid>
    <local:DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyleKey}">
```

I want to avoid them referencing the `x:Key` for simplicity and maintainability reasons.

---

What I am looking for is a way that combines the best of both solutions: Setting the `Row/CellStyles` as Default Styles to avoid the need to reference hard-coded `x:Key` strings, but also avoid overriding Default Styles of the standard WPF `DataGrid`. The only other solution I can think of is using custom controls for `DataGridCell` and other sub-controls too. Is this a viable solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to declare the style from your first approach in the scope of default style from your custom DataGrid as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="local:DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="CellStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <!-- Your Default Style here -->
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This will not override default DataGrids CellStyle and can been changed by user easily.

Comment: I just tried that, but can't figure out how users can extend my standard Style when creating a custom DataGrid in XAML. By using `<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">` it is still referencing the standard WPF DataGrid, but I want them to take my custom DataGrid Style as basis.

Comment: With this the users easily can only set new styles. Using the Cellstyle as basis is not possible with that. By using BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}" you refrence to basic style from a type. Because your custom DataGrid doesn't provide a new type for DataGridCell, there is no way to decide between customs DataGrid CellStyle and global ones (these styles are independend from DataGrid...).